# installing oracle Database 11g Release 2 in linux 7

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g

I wanted to install the  oracle Database 11g Release 2 in linux 7 using NFS, Can I know if there any significant change on this and 12cr1 release installation steps.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/oracle-db-12cr1-rac-installation-on-oracle-linux-7-using-nfs

Comment: This would probably get better answers on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Tim provides a whole raft of articles for installing 11gR2 on Linux/ Why not [read some of them](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/articles-11g#db11g_release_2_installations)????